# about UITableView touch event

Tags: iphone, uitableview, touch

I put a tableview assigned to the right as a `UIViewController`.

```
`self.view = tableview.view;`
```

I wrote a touch event in `UIViewController`.

But tableview complete coverage of this `UIViewController`, so we can not respond to a touch event.

So I rewrote the touch event tableView.

is OK now.

However, it also left behind a small bit of the next issue

Is touchMoved time, not very smooth, drop frame.

ps: this time, I did not load any data inside the tableView.

So it can be concluded, not because of load data is not caused by fluid. . .

Because certainly in other places! ! !

There is, perhaps you will think there is another better way to solve this case can easily transfer problems

That is the value by setting userInteractionEnabled response touch to control whether the control message.

But the tragedy is that God always hope when you come to a head with a brick. .

Why then? we try to think about it! Think about it will know, or you can try.

Speaking just before the drop frame of the problem, but also hope to discuss with you ah. .

Perfect solution, I will open the way out!

Thanks all.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question. I do not understand your question. And please provide code.

Comment: Ouch.This one is weird..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confused about the difference between a view and a view controller.

A UIViewController does not display on the screen: it's a class that handles controller logic related to a view (in your case a table view). The table view displays on the screen, the view controller just exists to supply it with data and respond to messages sent by the table view.

Regarding the dropped frames issue, what are you trying to do in `touchMoved`?